# How to find the normal equation of a plane given two lines?

Tags: calculus

Determine a normal equation for the plane with lines $l_1 = (1-2t,1/2t,2+t)$ and $l_2 = (1-t,t,2+2t)$.

What I have so far:
$$
l_1 = (1,0,2)+t(-2,1/2,1)\\
l_2 = (1,0,2)+t(-1,1,2)
$$

$$l_1 \times l_2 = (0,3,-3/2)$$

From here, I'm confused as to the next steps, how do I get to the equation form from this?

Comment: Can you elucidate a little further?

Comment: If you want to ask more questions on this site, it's recommended to use the mathjax (latex) formatting to ask. [There is a tutorial here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0):

You've got the direction of the normal correctly, $n=(0,3,-3/2)$, (checked with [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=cross+product+of+%28-2%2C1%2F2%2C1%29+and+%28-1%2C1%2C2%29)). The equation of the plane is $n\cdot((x,y,z)-d)=0$, where $d$ is any point on the plane, and you've got an obvious point you can use as $d$ which is $(1,0,2)$, so your normal equation for the plane is
$$2y-z+2=0.\tag{1}$$

Please check this by inserting your equations for $l_1$ and $l_2$ into (1) and checking that they are satisfied.

Conceptually, if a point $(x,y,z)$ is on the plane, then its dot product with the normal is equal to the dot product of any other point on the plane with that normal.

Answer (score 0):

The equation of the plane is $\vec n.\vec r=d$, $\vec n=(0,3,-3/2)$. We get $3y-3z/2=d$ by putting the point $(1,0,2)$, we get $d=-3$.